# Unable to compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.11' in Android Studio with Gradle

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, itext, itextg

Defining the dependency of the version `5.5.10`:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
}
```

works fine.

But `5.5.11` or `5.5.12` do not compile.

Has this been released yet? If not, any idea when it may be?

Answer (score 9):

I am QA & release engineer at iText Software, and I am possibly best placed to answer this question.
iTextG 5.5.11 and 5.5.12 have not yet been released. That is in the backlog, and not yet planned. It certainly won't happen this month.

Are there any changes in 5.5.11 or 5.5.12 that you urgently need? Because they are bugfix releases, without any new features, and if you are not affected by the fixed bugs, then there is no need to upgrade. See iText changelogs for more details (on the iText website, or the git log on GitHub).

Comment: Thanks for ur comment.It helped me a lot

Comment: Then please update your site:
in https://developers.itextpdf.com/itextg-android, you clearly specify:

`compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.11'`

Comment: Or release iTextG 5.5.11, 5.5.12 and 5.5.13.

Comment: I just created the Jira tickets to do that.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse is there any update planned for itextg? A lot of time is passed from the last 5.5.10 release

Comment: It's still in the backlog.

Answer (score 5):

Using the version `5.5.11` indicated in the docs:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.11'
}
```

or the latest release `5.5.13` doesn´t work, probably it doesn´t exists for download via gradle:

[image]

I had to change to :

```
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
```

Comment: As stated in my answer, versions 5.5.11, 5.5.12 and 5.5.13 of iTextG are not yet released.

Answer (score 0):

Also import following class to generate pdf

```
import com.itextpdf.text.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
```

You can also refer more methods and techniques to generate pdf with inbuilt facility on below official link:

https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-1

If anyone like my help to make it easy than give Up Arrow and Right Click for the same.

Thankyou.

Comment: Your "dependency to update to" is exactly what the OP originally said that he knew to work fine. And your imports don't make that much sense, why do you import individual classes after already importing `*`?